# How to connect to a database with semicolon in the name?

Tags: php, pdo

I have a database which has a semicolon in the name e.g. `a;a`. I can't rename the database. In SQL I would use the backticks to escape the name, but how can I do it in PDO DSN?

```
$db = 'a;a';
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$db;charset=utf8mb4";
$options = [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
];
try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int) $e->getCode());
}
```

Since `;` is used as a separator in the DSN, PDO thinks my database is called `a` and I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'a'

Comment: Why would you have semicolon in database name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it by using double semicolon.

```
$db = 'a;;a'; // <-- means the database is called `a;a`
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$db;charset=utf8mb4";
```